# Trying to Embed Cordova app into Native Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, native, hybrid

When I try to follow the guide of Cordova to embed it into a native android application I can't build.

I use this guide:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

When I put everything in my main activity I receive an error on `config`.
It says can't resolve symbol 'config'. I have no clue what I am doing wrong or how to solve it.

**onCreate**

```
 /* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
    config.init(this);
    cwv.loadUrl(config.getStartUrl());
}
```

Comment: The 'C' - It's Config, you're using config.

Comment: I just downvoted this question since the error (config should have been Config with capital 'C') has not been corrected.